# Format mailto link so that PHP can cleanly interpret it

Tags: javascript, php, html, mailto

How do I format a `mailto:` protocol so that way PHP can interpret it in the following fashion:

```
//General PHP test:
print_r($_GET);

//Desired output:
Array
(
 [mailto] => me@example.com
 [subject] => Test Subject
 [body] => Placeholder body example.
 [bcc] => you@example.com
 [cc] => them@example.com
)
```

Currently I've got `mailto:test@example.com&subject=The%20Subject&body=Some+test+text.` though it gets interpreted as:

```
Array
(
 [mailto:test@example_com&subject=The%20Subject&body=Some+test+text_] => 
)
```

Comment: The mailto URL's format is incorrect:  its format should be "mailto:test@example.com?subject=A&body=B".

Comment: @PeterO. Thank you, that works with Kinjal's answer. ︀

Comment: Note the question mark between the "com" and "subject"; it's not ampersand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are willing to make a small change to the input string, instead of `mailto:from@example.com` you are willing to put an equals sign like `mailto=from@example.com` then the following code makes it easy:

```
$querystr = "mailto=test@example.com&subject=The%20Subject&body=Some+test+text";
$array = array();

parse_str($querystr, $array);

print_r($array);
```

output is:

```
Array ( [mailto] => test@example.com [subject] => The Subject [body] => Some test text )
```

Comment: Lots of bad code on the web however this works in conjunction with Peter O.'s comment about the malformed format. Thank you. The anchor `href` value that works is `mailto:test@example.com&#38;subject=A&#38;body=B&#38;bcc=you@example.com&#38;cc=them@example.com`.